# Perl Regex match incorrect

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a little confused as to why the output to this search is only the capital letter T. Shouldn't the + operator match the entire word "GREAT"? Any help is appreciated.

```
my $content = "The 39 Steps - a GREAT book - colours_15";

    if($content =~ /([A-Z]+)/) {
        print "Matched $1\n";
    }
    else {
        print "No match\n";
    }
```

Comment: It is the `T` from `The`.

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew, it matches the `T` only. This is because you're looking for one or more CAPITAL letters consecutively. Once it hits the `h`, the regex stops matching (and capturing) because the `h` is lower-case.

Comment: Note that if you change the case of "The" to "the", it will stop at the "S" of "Steps".

Comment: `Shouldn't the + operator match the entire word "GREAT"?` Yes, it will, eventually. If you change it to `while ( $data =~ /([A-Z]+)/g ) { print $1,"\n"; }` you will eventually match `GREAT`.  This is basic stuff. You should read the basics before asking questions. Otherwise, you may get answers you don't understand, like _boundary's_ and _regex debugging_ that would be way beyond your comprehension, and totally useless.

Answer (score 6):

The `T` you printed is the first capital letter found by your regex.  It is the `T` from the first `The` word.

If you want to match *all* occurrences of 1+ capital ASCII letter chunks in a larger string, use your pattern with a `g` ("global") modifier: `/[A-Z]+/g`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$s = "The 39 Steps - a GREAT book - colours_15";
my @res = $s =~ /[A-Z]+/g;
say "@res";
```

See the [online Perl demo](https://ideone.com/MfXeL4) printing `T S GREAT`.

If you want to find a *whole word* that only consists of ALLCAPS letters, use

```
/\b([A-Z]+)\b/
```

The `\b` is a word boundary and will ensure whole word matches.

Note that you might also match `GREAT` here by using `/([A-Z]{2,})/` regex that matches 2 or more capital ASCII letters, but the version with word boundaries looks more practical.

Answer (score 4):

The regex engine starts at the left of the string. It tries to match capital letters, at least one and as many as possible. That's the `T` from `The`. That's at least one, and then it's done. It never even reaches the `GREAT`.

You can see that if you run your program with `use re 'debug'`, which turns on [regex debugging](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#'debug'-mode).

```
use re 'debug';

"The 39 Steps - a GREAT book - colours_15" =~ /([A-Z]+)/;
```

This will write to STDERR:

```
Compiling REx "([A-Z]+)"
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   PLUS (15)
   4:     ANYOF[A-Z][] (0)
  15: CLOSE1 (17)
  17: END (0)
stclass ANYOF[A-Z][] plus minlen 1 
Matching REx "([A-Z]+)" against "The 39 Steps - a GREAT book - colours_15"
Matching stclass ANYOF[A-Z][] against "The 39 Steps - a GREAT book - colours_15" (40 bytes)
   0 <> <The 39 Ste>         |  1:OPEN1(3)
   0 <> <The 39 Ste>         |  3:PLUS(15)
                                  ANYOF[A-Z][] can match 1 times out of 2147483647...
   1 <T> <he 39 Step>        | 15:  CLOSE1(17)
   1 <T> <he 39 Step>        | 17:  END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "([A-Z]+)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This. This will give you perfect result.

my $content = "The 39 Steps - a GREAT book - colours_15";

```
if($content =~m /\b([A-Z]+)\b/){
    print "Matched $1\n";
}
else{
    print "No match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Perl regex engine is lazy. It will return the leftmost match in your string. As soon as it finds a match, it will stop looking for "better" matches.

The regex engine's internal dialogue for this code might go something like this:

> Ok, so we're looking for one or more capital letters. Right, so let's start looking at this string. What's the first character? Oh, a capital 'T'. That matches. But we're looking for one or more characters, so keep looking. What's next? A lower-case 'h'. Ok, that doesn't match. Looks like we're done then. The first sequence of one or more capital letters I found was just the letter 'T'. Stick that in `$1` and it looks like we can knock off early. Who's putting the kettle on?